# Order By not working on datetime 101 format

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

```
Create table #temp
(
OrderDate datetime
)

insert into #temp values ('01/21/2015'),('01/20/2014'),('11/12/2013')

select distinct convert(varchar(10),orderdate,101) as OrderDate  from #temp 
order by convert(varchar(10),orderdate,101) asc
```

The above query gives me the result like below:

```
OrderDate
01/20/2014
01/21/2015
11/12/2013
```

But I want the result like below:

```
OrderDate
11/12/2013
01/20/2014
01/21/2015
```

The above is just a sample on which I am trying to do sorting on format **101**. In my actual query I need to use **distinct** keyword and also the columns will come dynamically in the select statement by using parameter.

I can't use group by in my actual query.

Please help.

Comment: You are ordering by the string representation of your date instead of the datetime value.

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE**

Referring to your comments the only way I've managed to get the **UNIQUE** results with only one column `orderdate` converted to `VARCHAR` 101 representation while still sorting it according to `DATETIME` sort order, was using a little workaround with `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), A.OrderDate, 101) as orderdate
FROM 
    #temp AS A
GROUP BY
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), A.OrderDate, 101) 
ORDER BY 
    MAX(A.OrderDate) ASC
```

`MAX(A.OrderDate)` should always give you the exactly equal value to the value of every group, so it shouldn't be an improper way - I've put a working example with repeats under the following link on **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a2438/1)**.

Still maybe the previous two-columned solution would happen to occur helpful:

```
select distinct 
    convert(varchar(10),orderdate,101) as OrderDateConverted,
    orderdate
from 
    #temp 
order by 
    orderdate asc
```

The above query sorts your query results according to `DATETIME` datatype whereas `order by convert(varchar(10),orderdate,101)` caused the alphanumeric sort order.

Comment: Yes, really sorry - now it's corrected. The `order by` column must be in select clause column list also, so unfortunately it has to be added whereas column converted to VARCHAR with 101 option was renamed. I hope that now it helps at least slightly in solving your problem

Comment: No, I can't do this like above as I also mentioned in my question that I have query in which I pick the select columns dynamically from the parameter from a table and from the same table I pick the Order by columns so its very sure the column structure will be gonna same in order by clause too.

Comment: According to the above query it will return me two columns but my requirement in my work is just to sore the column which is in the select list.

Comment: @GarvitGupta it is pretty simple to remove the second column from the select list. Not sure what you mean about the select list being dynamic. Are you saying that you have some code that has OrderDate but builds up a string and executes it using the convert logic? The more I look at this the less it is making sense.

Comment: @GarvitGupta Please find the updated answer - maybe it could fit your needs - it contains only 1 column and has a working example on SQL Fiddle included. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can use subQuery as follows to solve the issue.

```
SELECT t.OrderDate FROM (
SELECT distinct Convert(VARCHAR(10), orderdate, 101) AS OrderDate
  from #temp ) t
order by     cast(t.OrderDate AS DATETIME) asc
```